# Can Unicode NFC normalization increase the length of a string?

Tags: unicode, normalization, utf, unicode-normalization

If I apply Unicode Normalization Form C to a string, will the number of code points in the string ever increase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are code points that expand to multiple code points after applying NFC normalization. Within the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane), for example, there are 70 code points that expand to 2 code points after applying NFC normalization, and there are 2 code points (U+FB2C and U+FB2D within the [Alphabetic Presentation Forms block](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFB00.pdf)) that expand to 3 code points.

One guarantee that you have for this so-called "expansion factor" is that no string will ever expand more than 3 times in length (in terms of number of [code units](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#code_unit)) after NFC normalization is applied:

> There is also a Unicode Consortium stability policy that canonical mappings are always limited in all versions of Unicode, so that no string when decomposed with NFC expands to more than 3× in length (measured in code units). This is true whether the text is in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32. This guarantee also allows for certain optimizations in processing, especially in determining buffer sizes.

Section 9, [Detecting Normalization Forms](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Detecting_Normalization_Forms). UAX #15: Unicode Normalization Forms.

I have written a Java program to determine which code points within a Unicode block expand to multiple code points: http://ideone.com/9PUOCb

Alternatively, [Tom Christiansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist)'s [`unichars`](http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/Unicode-Tussle/script/unichars) utility, part of the Unicode::Tussle CPAN module, can be used. (Note: Mac users may see an error at the `make test` installation step saying that the Perl version is too old. If you see this error, you can install the module by running `notest install Unicode::Tussle` within a CPAN shell.)

Examples:

- Print the code points in the BMP that expand to 3 code points:

  ```
  unichars 'length(NFC) == 3'
  ```

  ```
  ‭‭ שּׁ  U+FB2C HEBREW LETTER SHIN WITH DAGESH AND SHIN DOT
  ‭ שּׂ  U+FB2D HEBREW LETTER SHIN WITH DAGESH AND SIN DOT
  ```
- Count the number of code points in all planes that expand to more than one code point:

  ```
  unichars -a 'length(NFC) > 1' | wc -l
  ```

  ```
        85
  ```

See also the frequently asked question [What are the maximum expansion factors for the different normalization forms?](http://www.unicode.org/faq/normalization.html#12)

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of work. `unichars 'length(NFC) > 1' | wc -l` is 72 for the BMP, and adding `-a` to include all planes yields 85.

Comment: @tchrist: [`unichars`](http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/Unicode-Tussle/script/unichars) looks like a neat tool. I'll have to install it and give it a try :)